# unknown files rot my cpanel and I can no longer use it correctly

Tags: wordpress, security, cpanel, vps, cpanel-xmlapi

I have a real problem on my cpanel I do not understand all my sites and my applications have not worked since this morning, try to restore without success I have tried everything, I am afraid to watch help me.
when I check the files of my site and application there are unknown files that create themselves all the time even when I delete completely when I update it comes back alone and it affects the operation of my site and application
I don't know if I was really hacked, or if it's an extension problem, or it's a quota or php problem but nothing's going well here are some images of the unknown folders, I've already written to support they say they will delete the hosting and create a new one when I can't afford it right now[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, you have really messed up your WordPress Core. Firstly, fix your .htaccess and 'delete the folders'. Additionally, you can always reinstall WordPress Core to fix any problems that might have happened from a Malware action.

However, there has been a rise in WordPress Database Malware as well, so you might wanna look in that as well.

Comment: I don't use wordpress at all, the files you see will appear in all the folders of the entire website, that is to say 16 pure html css sites none of them is wordpress

Comment: HTML/CSS doesn't get hacked. Only server side code, i.e PHP are vulnerable to attacks! Maybe check your user directory for PHP files.